# Can't import Materialize CSS JS react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, materialize

Good morning everyone,

I've been struggling to get materialize css to work on my react-app, specifically, the Javascript files.

I've tried multiple ways, but this is the one I think i've gotten farther.

In my 'landingpage.js' file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles/css/custom.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'materialize-css'; // It installs the JS asset only
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/js/modal';
```

The objective is to open a simple popup (so I can test if the JS is being imported correctly)

```
            <div>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
            <div id="modal1" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <h4>Modal Header</h4>
                <p>A bunch of text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
```

So, as soon as the component mounts:

```
   componentDidMount() {
    $('.modal').modal();
}
```

When I click the button, it's supposed to open a popup, however:

```
ReferenceError: Component is not defined
```

This error occurs on the JS file i'm trying to import.

I tried importing in many different ways and the app would not even recognize anything. I've been trying to import this for two days and searched the web a lot, I'm doing this for a School Final project, trying to self learn react.

Here's the link to the framework i'm trying to import:

```
https://materializecss.com/modals.html#!
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to include the CSS in your html

Comment: It is already imported. The CSS works fine, the JS does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add your full path from npm module into your entry point file for webpack to utilize your css...

here is an example in a typical create-react-app using Index.js or what ever your calling it if you are doing your own react boilerplate.

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'; // <---

import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Once this is done your components will be able to have access to the css properties. I also recommend you install the `npm i -S materialize-css@next` so you can use JS components without needing JQuery

Answer (score 1):

using jquery with react is not recommended at all 
if you trying to use material how about using a library like

[material-ui](https://www.material-ui.com/#/)
 install it by using

```
npm i material-ui --save
```

and you can follow the example here for dialog which is basically a modal 
[dialog in material ui](https://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've looked into material-UI and it works well with react, however, I'm not very fond of its documentation as I'm still a newbie. I find materializecss's documentation to be much clearer and easy to follow. I'm just a JS import away from having it all working :(