# React - how to add jquery script with Materialize's function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, materialize

Hello I'd like to add jquery to a react app, but I don't know how to do it. I use materialize to build a navbar and I want to use .sidenav function from their lib.

I installed jquery

```
npm install jquery
```

and add

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

to ./app.js, then in Navbar.js i got /

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <nav className="nav-wraper">
        <div className="container">
          <a Link to="/" className="brand-logo">
            Blog
          </a>
          <a Link to="/" className="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-links">
            <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
          </a>
          <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/create">New Blog</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/create">New Blog</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/signup">Sign up</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Where am I supposed to put this code?:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".sidenav").sidenav();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way, you don't need to use `$(document).ready` statement. instead of that, you can use `useEffect` with an empty deps array (`[]`) in *functional components* or `componentDidMount` in *class components*. see the below example:
(Remember to use Materilized-css CDNs in index.html).
In functional component (As you are):

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import M from 'materialize-css';
    
const Navbar = () => {
    const myNavbar = useRef('');
    useEffect(() => {
        M.Sidenav.init(myNavbar);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="nav-wraper" ref={myNavbar}>...</ul>
        </>
    );
};
export default Navbar;
```

For more information about **useEffect** and **useRef** statements, i would like to refer you to the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).sidenav is not a function - in $(".sidenav").sidenav();

Comment: Did you import `materialize` in your component?

Comment: Remember that you should first import `React`. then `jQuery` and  at the end `materialize`.

Comment: Yes, I did it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389269/cant-import-materialize-css-js-react   I got import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'; in index.js and I installed materialize by terminal command

Comment: Even if I add: import "materialize-css/js/sidenav.js"; to a navbar.js compontent it show the same error

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? so i can see your full codes.

Comment: I think you should import `materialize` in public>index.html. the `<script>` before closing `</body>` and the `<link>` inside the `<head></head>`

Comment: I added them before.  https://jsfiddle.net/gdfrj826/  I dont know if I did it right. I need to learn more about useEffect and useState.

Comment: I found your solution. first you need to install `materialized-css` package by running this command: `yarn add materialize-css@next`. and then go to [get start with materialized documentation](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) and use the CDN way (import CDNs in index.html). at the end see my  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrghafouri/odxt8wku/7/) to find out how you can use materilizes in your `ReactJs` project as well.

Comment: For more information about `useEffect` and `useRef` hooks, plz read [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) and In general, I am against the use of `Materilized-css` in `ReactJs`. there is already a very beautiful, helpful and easy library named [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/). i use this library every times in my projects. It has a navbar too.

Comment: It still doesn.t work. It show no errors, but the menu (hamburger menu) doesn't collapse.

Comment: There are a lot of problems, so I'm gonna change to start learning material-ui.